# Adding and Storing 400+ lines of string into ListView SubiIems

Tags: c#

Could someone give me a tips for adding 400+ lines of strings into ListView SubItems?
I'm adding them so that I don't need to downlaod the strings again and I can preview into Listbox everytime I click on ListView

I'm able to add but the problem is, the performance of my form is slowing and the scrolling is slow also.

Here's my code for adding them

```
       var fragments = await GetFragment(info, token); //download fragments/strings

        var results = new List<ListViewItem> { new ListViewItem(new[]
        {
            info.Title,
            info.Runtime,
            info.Resolution,
            fragments, //here's the 400+ lines of strings
        })};
        ListViewItem[] array = results.ToArray();

        LV.BeginUpdate();
        LV.ListViewItemSorter = null;

        foreach (ListViewItem i in array)
        { i.Checked = true; }

        LV.Items.AddRange(array);
        ReSizeColumns();
        LV.Focus();
        LV.Items[LV.Items.Count - 1].EnsureVisible();
        LV.Items[LV.Items.Count - 1].Selected = true;
        LV.EndUpdate();
```

here's the screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom/derived `ListViewItem` class and add as many extra properties as you need to hold non-display information.

```
public class CustomListViewItem : ListViewItem
{
    public CustomListViewItem() : base() { }

    public CustomListViewItem(String[] items)
        : base (items)
    {

    }

    public String[] Fragments { get; set; }
}
```

The line containing:

```
var results = new List<ListViewItem> { new ListViewItem(new[]
{
    info.Title,
    info.Runtime,
    info.Resolution,
    fragments, //here's the 400+ lines of strings
})};
```

will change to be:

```
var results = new List<CustomListViewItem> { new CustomListViewItem(new[]
{
    info.Title,
    info.Runtime,
    info.Resolution,
})};
results[0].Fragments = fragments;
```

I only added two constructors (the default one, and the one I think you are using), you should add as many as you need.

When handling any of the events and wanting to get to the new propery, you will need to cast from the `ListViewItem` class to your new `CustomListViewItem`

```
private void LV_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CustomListViewItem customListViewItem = LV.SelectedItems[0] as CustomListViewItem;

    if (customListViewItem != null)
    {
        // Do things with the CustomListViewItem
        Debug.WriteLine(customListViewItem.Fragments);        }
    }
}

private void LV_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    CustomListViewItem customListViewItem = e.Item as CustomListViewItem;

    if (customListViewItem != null)
    {
        // Do things with the CustomListViewItem
        Debug.WriteLine(customListViewItem.Fragments);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thank for that. I'm gonna test it now.

So it will also store the 400+ lines?
I mean, even if I select other items, I can also preview the existing 400 lines?

Comment: @zackmark15 Well, the 400+ lines are stored and available in the object. When you handle the event, the lines are available to do with as you wish. Also, I made a small edit to the `DoubleClick` handler to demonstrate this.

Comment: I'm getting this error when selecting items and preview to textbox
I can only preview the first item

'InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.

Comment: Oh wow that's really great that's what I'm looking so that I don't have to restore inside the  listview subitems. but just a little error

Comment: @zackmark15 I should add that I assumed that the text fragments was an Array of Strings. If this isn't correct, you should change it

Comment: Oh I got it. I didn't notice you have updated the code. It worked now

Comment: Yes I already changed the strings[] to string :) 
I'll post later the final code.

Comment: Its a custom class, you can use it to store what you like as long as you don't break the functionality of the base ListViewItem. I have customised the ListView to hold large files, various identifying data, links to other forms/objects. Anything that is related to a single ListViewItem

Comment: Oh I see. thank you for this. I will always use this from now on

Comment: The new problem may require a new question with the problem code added to it. Lets not confuse matters by editing this question too much with a new problem

Comment: Alright :) I'll try to figure out. 
I"ll just gonna fix and post later the final code

Comment: One last thing. how to use this? 
  public CustomListViewItem(string[] items)
            : base(items) { }

Comment: In order to use a specific constructor in the base class, you have to have a compatible one in the derived class. This particular constructor takes an array of Strings and passes it to the base (ListViewItem) constructor. From reading your code, it seemed to me to be the one (of twenty-three) that you were using. If you don't think you are using it, you can delete those lines

Comment: I have posted my new question here. I know you only the  one can answer it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63005588/serialize-and-deserialize-listview-items?noredirect=1#comment111417752_63005588